# Closed form for binomial coeff sum

Tags: binomial-coefficients

As part of a proof in finite group theory, I'm looking for a closed
form for the expression

$$\sum_{i=j+1}^{n} \binom{\binom{i}{j}}{2}$$

Any help - especially with reference or proof - would be
appreciated.  In the group theory context, there is strong evidence
that the overall result is correct, but having a closed form here would
be the most obvious way to construct a proof.

I don't know if a closed form exists, but computation of
special cases suggests the sum is equal to

$$\frac{(n-j)(n-(j-1))...(n-1)n(n+1)p_j(n)}{(2j+1)!}$$

Where $p_j(n)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $j-1$.
In fact, the leading coefficient of $p_j$ appears to be $\binom{2j-1}{j-1}$.
In general $p_j$ is not irreducible.

I really just need to know that factor of $(n+1)$ is present, but to
prove that by induction on $n$ it seems I would need a precise formula for $p_j$.
Since I can compute $p_j$ for given $j$, I know this formula is correct
for $j=1,2,3,$ and $4$.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think there is a closed form?

Comment: Why was this question closed as "off-topic"?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=j+1}^n {i \choose j}$$ has a simple closed form.

It appears that
$$ \sum_{i=j+1}^n {i \choose j}^2 = \lim_{x \to 1-} \left(\left( j+1 \right) ^{2}{x}^{j+1}
{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(1,j+2,j+2;\,2,2;\,x)}-  {n+1\choose j}
  ^{2}{x}^{n+1}{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(1,2+n,2+n;\,2+n-j,2+n-j;\,x)}
 \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to show that the factor $n+1$ is present.

**Theorem.** Let $p(i)$ be a polynomial. Then there exists a polynomial $P(n)$ such that for $i\ge0$ we have $\sum_{i=0}^n p(i)= P(n)$, and $P(n)$ is divisible by $n+1$.

*Proof.* The existence of the polynomial $P(n)$ is well known. To show that $P(n)$ is divisible by $n+1$ it suffices to show that $P(-1) = 0$. But
$$P(n) = -p(-1) +\sum_{i=-1}^n p(i),$$
and this formula is valid for $n\ge-1$. Thus $P(-1) = -p(-1) +p(-1) =0$.

A slightly different point of view makes this result seem more obvious. Let $p$ be a polynomial. Then by finite differences or otherwise there is a unique polynomial $Q$ such that $Q(i+1)-Q(i)=p(i)$ for all $i$ (all we need is $i\ge0$) and $Q(0) = 0$. By induction, we have $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p(i) = Q(n)$ for all $n\ge0$, where, as usual, $\sum_{i=0}^{-1}$ is 0 by definition. Since $Q(0) =0$, $Q(n)$ is divisible by $n$, so $\sum_{i=0}^n p(i) = Q(n+1)$ is divisible by $n+1$.

Another (slightly more complicated, but self-contained) way to prove the theorem is to note that it holds for the basis of polynomials $p(i) = \binom{i}{k}$, since $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$, which is divisible by $n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica says:

$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\frac{\Gamma (-j-1) \Gamma (-j) \binom{n+1}{j} \Gamma
   (-j+n+2)}{\Gamma (-j+n+1)}+\Gamma (-2 j-1)}{\Gamma (-j)^2}-\binom{n+1}{j}^2 \,
   _3F_2(1,n+2,n+2;-j+n+2,-j+n+2;1)\right)
$$
I am not quite sure what to make of the Gammas with negative integer arguments, but there you have it.

Comment: (revised comment) Mathematica's Binomial function works for fairly arbitrary inputs, and Mathematica will attempt to simplify symbolic expressions using Binomial in whatever manner has been coded into it as the "natural" thing to assume you meant.  In this case, it is assuming by default that $j$ is not a positive integer (since that is the case that's problematic).  If you force it to assume this, with say `Assuming[Element[j,Integers]&& j>0, rest of code ]`, then it will not produce this output and will just leave it exactly as calls to Binomial.